# Is HTTP accepting a json format object called Rest architecture?

Tags: json, rest, http, soap

I have been working Rest and json using spring framework.

I have got couple of doubts.

1)Is http transferring data in the form of json can be called Rest.I know http is protocol and Rest is architectural style?

2)Can any application (url) that accepts data in the form of json(sent from any client) called Rest?

2)why soap protocal is using http under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReST is an architectural style which is completely independent of either HTTP or JSON. ReST really only talks about modelling a domain as a set of 'resources'. Any resource has a unique identifier which distinguishes it from other resources. Clients interact with resources using a common protocol and resources are created / modified / deleted through manipulating their representations.

HTTP and JSON are both aspects of specific implementations of a ReSTful architecture. HTTP is a good transport mechanism for ReSTful applications, providing a common API in the form of HTTP's set of verbs - GET, PUT, POST, DELETE. JSON is a good document transfer format and so is often used to implement the 'representation' aspect of ReST, but ReSTful applications can use other document formats if they choose - you can find ReSTful applications which use XML, JPEG, AVI, MP3, ...

Neither HTTP nor JSON is specifically ReSTful and its entirely possible to find HTTP applications using JSON which are not ReSTful at all. Similarly, not every ReSTful application will use JSON or HTTP (although I've never seen a real application in the wild which doesn't use HTTP/HTTPS).

Comment: I have one doubt .Which kind of http applications are using JSON but not restful? and also have you ever seen any restful app not using http (how transport will be handled in this case)?

Comment: If i have built an HTTP application which can process JSON input and gives proper output in JSON , then can we call the application is following  Restful architecture?.

Comment: You can build a ReSTful application using any transport mechanism - HTTP is not the only protocol. And a HTTP application which accepts JSON may or may not be ReSTful. If it acts like an old school CGI application then it won't be ReSTful.

Answer (score 1):

Rest is not all about JSON, you have also the verbs GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and the http code for your answers which are involved.

If you post JSON for every action then it's not restful

In REST everything is a resource.

HTTP is an application layer. It's has nothing really with REST concept. You see a webpage via http and this is not REST at all. So SOAP can also use http.

HTTP is not bind to REST but REST is bind to HTTP

Answer (score 1):

As stated in other comments, RESTful is an architecture, but not a language or coding paradigm.

RESTful:
Something anti-REST would be JSON-RPC (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC). The Framework is a Remote Procedure Call Lib. JSON-RPC would definitely not be RESTful since the RPC layer maps urls to functions (i.e. verbs) rather than particular resources (i.e. nouns). So rather than POSTing to some resource, you are calling a method, yet JSON as the format to serialize the data. There are tradeoffs to each.  It just so happens RESTful APIs are very common for public ones as many believe documentation can be clearer to outsiders.

JSON:
On the other hand, one could develop a RESTful architecture and not use JSON. There are many serialization libs, each with tradeoffs such as compression and schema-less vs something closer to type safety. Examples besides JSON would include MessagePack and Google's ProtoBufs. Of coarse, you could even use XML, although uncommon with RESTful APIs. JSON is used a lot in public APIs since pretty much any language can do JSON serialization with low 3rd party over head (i.e. not importing specific libs)